# std::vector of function pointers: different template parameters

Tags: c++, stl, function-pointers

Why does the following compile

```
std::vector<int(*)(double)> func_ptrs;
```

but this does not

```
std::vector<int(double)> func_ptrs
```

?

I get one of those ugly STL error messages in the second case, so I'm not going to put everything here, but at the end of the message I get this

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:102:30: error: ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type ‘int (*)(double)’ [-fpermissive]
for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
```

This seems to imply that C++ cast the type `int(double)` to `int (*) (double)`. I was under the impression that `int(*)(double)` and `int(double)` are equivalent anyway? Or am I wrong?

Would like to have some clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int(double)` is actually a function type, not a function pointer. It decays to function pointer in many cases, but not here. You can't use `sizeof` with a function type, for example - and that's vital for `vector`'s allocator.

As for your specific error: `add_pointer_t<int(double)>` (more or less this is used by `vector`'s iterator, internally or directly) is `int(*)(double)` and cannot be incremented, because it makes no sense to perform such operation.

Comment: ...and that's because the function type's size depends on the details of the function being implemented, and therefore you cannot know its size? (or rather, it does not have a predictable `sizeof` value)

Comment: Pretty much. It would also need an instance of a function, because the type itself wouldn't carry enough information.

Comment: You say that it does not decay into a function pointer in this case, but why does the error message refer to the fact that C++ may not increment the function *pointer*? Where did that pointer it refers to come from?

Comment: From the iterator. Say, if you have `vector<int>` it does handle `int*`s in the iterators (it may expose a different type as the iterator, but in the end that's what `it++` does)